# Which attribute should I use when push message in Firebase Cloud Messaging, 'text' or 'body'?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using push notification in Google Firebase Cloud Messaging API since 2016. But I got issue on 7th of January in 2020, and since then it doesn't work.

I'm finding right attribute for the API parameter.

Previously : `'notification' => ['text'=> $action]`

Changed (work) :  `'notification' => ['body'=> $action]`

Is `body` the right parameter?

If not how can I find the right parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) shows this example of a message body:

> ```
> {
>    "message":{
>       "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
>       "notification":{
>         "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
>         "title":"FCM Message"
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

So it looks like `body` is indeed the proper name for the property to use.